# How to search for a particular string with in a regex group with in a single regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the word 'noun' with in the last group of my regex.

So far I have:

```
tags = 'motocykl mutka 1 motorcycle bike moped 0 transportation openair noun'

print re.search('(?P<pol>\D+)(?P<d1>\d)(?P<eng>\D+)(?P<d2>\d)(?P<end>\D+)', tags).group('end')
```

All I get is a string which is that last group:

```
transportation openair noun
```

I need to just get:

```
noun
```

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to mention that 'noun' will not be showing up as the ***last*** word in some strings I will be running the regex against. For example:

```
tags = 'dźwig 1 crane 0 noun construction vehicle'
tags = 'trycykl 1 tricycle 0 child noun transportation'
```

**Any ideas on how to do this with in a single regex?**

Comment: It is not possible from your examples to guess the logic you will need. If the token will always be `noun` then why don't you match `noun` literally? If not, we only know that there can be several tokens and not how we can know which one of those.

Comment: Why do you want a single regex?  Can't you just do one regex to parse the line, and another one to strip out the 'noun' string from the last matched group?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your tags mean but `\D+?` should match "transportation openair" and the `[a-zA-Z]` will match the last word (noun):

`^(?P<pol>\D+)(?P<d1>\d)(?P<eng>\D+)(?P<d2>\d)\D+?(?P<end>[a-zA-Z]+)$`

Comment: I apologize but I did not explain myself well enough. The word 'noun' will not always be showing up as the last word in the string. Look at my updated question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are matching with `\D+`, which will match multiple words including spaces.  It makes perfect sense that you are getting the last group of words.

So you need to make your last group only match non-whitespace characters, and before your last group match on a whitespace character.

Here's a pattern that matches "transportation openair" in a group called "category" and correctly matches "noun" in the group "end".  Because we used the non-greedy `+` in matching `category`, we need a `$` to anchor the `end` group to actually be the last word in the string.

```
re.match(r'(?P<pol>\D+)(?P<d1>\d)(?P<eng>\D+)(?P<d2>\d)(?P<category>\D+?)\W+(?P<end>\w+)$', tags).group('end')
```

Comment: I apologize but I did not explain myself well enough. The word 'noun' will not always be showing up as the last word in the string. Look at my updated question for more details.