# How can we 1. search for a link/script/img with a particular structure and 2. pick up a user id from the matched string using a single regex?

Tags: python, regex

suppose an html source code has these tags link, img , src.

*Some* has below structure,

```
<link href="/users/id/111/myProfile">
...
<img src="/users/111/key_item">
...
<img src="/users/111/AAAAAAAAA.png">
...
<link href="/users/id/111/my_home">
...
<script src="/users/111/bbbb.js"
```

Using 2 separate regular expression I can find out the user id,

```
regex   = '<(script|img|link).*(src|href)=[\'\"][/]users/(id/|)[\d]+/.*[\'\"]'
pattern = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)
link    = pattern.search(html_source_code).group(0)

user_pattern = re.compile('[\d.]+', re.IGNORECASE)
user         = user_pattern.search(link).gourp(0)
```

I want to combine these two regex to a single one. 
That is a single regex to pick up the user id.

How can I use regex for this?

I saw an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458669/how-to-search-for-a-particular-string-with-in-a-regex-group-with-in-a-single-reg). But could not figure out a solution from that.

Comment: it's not generally a good idea to parse HTML with regex like that, you should use an HTML parser for that, then you could extract that value and to pull the user id you'd just `\/users(?:\/id)?\/([^\/]+)\/.*`

Comment: My requirement is to use regex only. I will get HTML code as a string. And for the regex, it should pick up user id from link/script/img .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to escape character `/` as `\/` in regex, second, you need to use a non-capturing group `(?: stuff)` for things you don't want to be captured, I fixed your regex as this, works with your examples:

`<(?:script|img|link).*(?:src|href)=[\'\"][\/]users\/(?:id\/|)([\d]+)\/.*[\'\"]`

Comment: That is giving me the entire match. I want only the user id. Only this in return:  "111".  Am using the regex inside pattern.search(string).group(0).

Comment: @m.j the syntax you're using actually returns the first text that was actually found, not the capturing group, the correct usage is using `re.findall` (something that returns groups not the found strings) or if you're seriously in need of using of re.search, `pattern.search(test).groups()[0]` would give you the result you're expecting (but still, regex for html and search for capturing groups are incorrect in your case)

Comment: That works!!! Thanks.  How does this groups() function selected only the user_id part!!  Is it becuase of the use of "?:" ? Can you please explain a little bit

Comment: @m.j I believe [This website](https://regex101.com/) would be awesome to teach you Regex, when you put your rules inside parenthesis, it'll capture that part as a group, when you do like `(?: )` it'll still treat it like a group, but it won't capture it, regex tutorials might help you a lot. I'm glad it's working for you.